# Apex Scatter Chart Not Displaying Correctly

Tags: javascript, html, apexcharts

I am building a scatter chart using HTML, Javascript, and Apex Charts. I make an API call to get data and then update the charts accordingly. So far everything has been working, but there's one specific data set that causes the chart to display all the dots on the same Y-Axis line, instead of scattered. I can't figure out why this would be.

I've created a minimal reproduction of the problem by creating two charts -- one with a data set that results in a working scatter chart, and one with a similar data set that results in a chart with all the dots on one line. See screenshots and code below, or check out the [codepen](https://codepen.io/Mickey_Vershbow/pen/OJojxoL?editors=1111).

[image: Working Chart]
[image: Incorrect Chart]

```js
$(function () {
  createChart1();
  createChart2();
});

const peopleData1 = [
  [114, 616],
  [74, 252],
  [45, 134],
  [40, 752],
  [27, 619],
  [21, 919],
  [21, 88],
  [20, 140],
  [18, 122],
  [15, 56],
  [15, 49],
  [14, 99],
  [13, 124],
  [13, 85],
  [13, 91],
  [13, 69],
  [12, 78],
  [11, 2299],
  [11, 59],
  [10, 42],
  [10, 175],
  [10, 319],
  [10, 55],
  [10, 86],
  [9, 5],
  [9, 28],
  [9, 108],
  [8, 51],
  [8, 86],
  [8, 72],
  [8, 49],
  [8, 89],
  [8, 109],
  [8, 245],
  [8, 366],
  [8, 190],
  [7, 25],
  [7, 70],
  [7, 13],
  [7, 85],
  [7, 160],
  [6, 243],
  [6, 53],
  [6, 34],
  [6, 44],
  [6, 643],
  [4, 2151],
  [5, 1528],
  [1, 1163],
  [1, 1133],
  [5, 697],
  [0, 621],
  [0, 579],
  [0, 338],
  [0, 315],
  [6, 308],
  [1, 301],
  [1, 299],
  [1, 276],
  [1, 270],
  [2, 264],
  [0, 256],
  [0, 245],
  [1, 239],
  [4, 237],
  [0, 236]
];
const peopleData2 = [
  ["9", "2162"],
  ["9", "555"],
  ["9", "809"],
  ["809", "4850"],
  ["8", "2151"],
  ["8", "74"],
  ["8", "58"],
  ["8", "821"],
  ["8", "650"],
  ["72", "5315"],
  ["7", "317"],
  ["7", "43"],
  ["68", "14791"],
  ["654", "2963"],
  ["6", "488"],
  ["6", "78"],
  ["6", "2122"],
  ["6", "320"],
  ["6", "1642"],
  ["6", "134"],
  ["6", "369"],
  ["5", "257"],
  ["5", "29"],
  ["5", "191"],
  ["5", "54"],
  ["5", "38"],
  ["5", "45"],
  ["5", "670"],
  ["457", "10056"],
  ["4", "24"],
  ["4", "536"],
  ["4", "44"],
  ["4", "157"],
  ["4", "174"],
  ["4", "128"],
  ["4", "126"],
  ["4", "75"],
  ["4", "106"],
  ["4", "137"],
  ["4", "117"],
  ["4", "129"],
  ["4", "26"],
  ["4", "372"],
  ["33", "483"],
  ["3", "237"],
  ["0", "992"],
  ["0", "99"],
  ["0", "99"],
  ["0", "99"],
  ["0", "99"],
  ["2", "98"],
  ["0", "98"],
  ["0", "98"],
  ["0", "98"],
  ["0", "97"],
  ["1", "97"],
  ["0", "97"],
  ["0", "97"],
  ["1", "97"],
  ["0", "96"],
  ["0", "96"],
  ["0", "95"],
  ["0", "95"],
  ["0", "95"],
  ["0", "95"],
  ["0", "95"],
  ["1", "95"],
  ["0", "94"],
  ["0", "94"],
  ["0", "94"],
  ["0", "94"],
  ["0", "94"],
  ["0", "94"],
  ["0", "94"],
  ["0", "94"],
  ["0", "94"],
  ["0", "94"],
  ["0", "936"],
  ["0", "93"],
  ["1", "93"],
  ["0", "93"],
  ["0", "93"],
  ["1", "93"],
  ["0", "93"],
  ["0", "93"],
  ["0", "92"],
  ["1", "92"],
  ["0", "92"],
  ["0", "92"],
  ["1", "92"],
  ["0", "92"],
  ["1", "91"]
];
const brandsData1 = [
  [533, 1384],
  [99, 59],
  [57, 5677],
  [55, 373],
  [38, 2608],
  [37, 438],
  [29, 6584],
  [29, 979],
  [27, 173],
  [21, 178],
  [21, 108],
  [16, 355],
  [14, 3439],
  [12, 65],
  [12, 22],
  [12, 73],
  [10, 48],
  [10, 102],
  [8, 67],
  [8, 64],
  [8, 108],
  [8, 129],
  [7, 73],
  [7, 4535],
  [7, 53],
  [6, 7],
  [6, 37],
  [6, 113],
  [6, 10],
  [5, 3270],
  [0, 1761],
  [1, 1477],
  [2, 1344],
  [4, 1166],
  [1, 1139],
  [6, 1099],
  [0, 992],
  [0, 966],
  [2, 938],
  [1, 803],
  [0, 749],
  [0, 650],
  [0, 564],
  [0, 559],
  [1, 545],
  [2, 484],
  [2, 479],
  [0, 472],
  [0, 457],
  [2, 453],
  [0, 415],
  [1, 389],
  [2, 382],
  [2, 356],
  [0, 340],
  [2, 302],
  [2, 300],
  [0, 293],
  [0, 274],
  [4, 244],
  [3, 242],
  [1, 239],
  [1, 239]
];
const brandsData2 = [
  ["9", "64"],
  ["7", "595"],
  ["7", "166"],
  ["7", "23"],
  ["7", "373"],
  ["61", "4126"],
  ["6", "448"],
  ["6", "47"],
  ["6", "117"],
  ["6", "200"],
  ["6", "2116"],
  ["6", "26"],
  ["6", "421"],
  ["6", "1151"],
  ["6", "309"],
  ["50", "292"],
  ["5", "70"],
  ["5", "35"],
  ["5", "426"],
  ["5", "790"],
  ["5", "26"],
  ["5", "141"],
  ["4", "1363"],
  ["4", "117"],
  ["4", "125"],
  ["4", "178"],
  ["4", "77"],
  ["4", "26"],
  ["31", "101"],
  ["3", "75"],
  ["0", "99"],
  ["0", "98"],
  ["0", "98"],
  ["0", "98"],
  ["0", "98"],
  ["0", "97"],
  ["1", "97"],
  ["0", "97"],
  ["0", "97"],
  ["0", "97"],
  ["0", "97"],
  ["13", "961"],
  ["0", "96"],
  ["0", "95"],
  ["0", "95"],
  ["1", "94"],
  ["0", "94"],
  ["0", "94"],
  ["1", "93"],
  ["0", "93"],
  ["0", "93"],
  ["0", "93"],
  ["0", "92"],
  ["0", "92"],
  ["2", "92"],
  ["0", "92"],
  ["0", "92"],
  ["2", "91"]
];

// Functions to create charts
const createChart1 = () => {
  var options = {
    series: [
      {
        name: "Brands",
        data: brandsData1
      },
      {
        name: "People",
        data: peopleData1
      }
    ],
    chart: {
      height: 350,
      id: "brands-people-chart",
      type: "scatter",
      zoom: {
        enabled: true,
        type: "xy"
      }
    },
    xaxis: {
      tickAmount: 10,
      labels: {
        show: false
      },
      title: {
        text: "Popularity",
        offsetX: 0,
        offsetY: 0,
        style: {
          fontSize: "12px",
          fontFamily: "Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif",
          fontWeight: 600,
          cssClass: "apexcharts-xaxis-title"
        }
      }
    },
    yaxis: {
      labels: {
        show: false
      },
      title: {
        text: "Influence",
        offsetX: 0,
        offsetY: 0,
        style: {
          fontSize: "12px",
          fontFamily: "Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif",
          fontWeight: 600,
          cssClass: "apexcharts-yaxis-title"
        }
      }
      // tickAmount: 7,
    },
    legend: {
      show: true,
      itemMargin: {
        horizontal: 5,
        vertical: 10
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: true
    }
  };

  var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart__1"), options);
  chart.render();
};

const createChart2 = () => {
  var options = {
    series: [
      {
        name: "Brands",
        data: brandsData2
      },
      {
        name: "People",
        data: peopleData2
      }
    ],
    chart: {
      height: 350,
      type: "scatter",
      zoom: {
        enabled: true,
        type: "xy"
      }
    },
    xaxis: {
      tickAmount: 10,
      labels: {
        show: false
      },
      title: {
        text: "Popularity",
        offsetX: 0,
        offsetY: 0,
        style: {
          fontSize: "12px",
          fontFamily: "Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif",
          fontWeight: 600,
          cssClass: "apexcharts-xaxis-title"
        }
      }
    },
    yaxis: {
      labels: {
        show: false
      },
      title: {
        text: "Influence",
        offsetX: 0,
        offsetY: 0,
        style: {
          fontSize: "12px",
          fontFamily: "Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif",
          fontWeight: 600,
          cssClass: "apexcharts-yaxis-title"
        }
      }
      // tickAmount: 7,
    },
    legend: {
      show: true,
      itemMargin: {
        horizontal: 5,
        vertical: 10
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: true
    }
  };

  var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart__2"), options);
  chart.render();
};
```

```css
#charts-parent-container {
  width: 70%;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

#chart-title__2 {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: larger;
}

#chart-title__1 {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: larger;
}
```

```html
<!-- Import Libraries -->
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Apex Charts -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>

<div id='charts-parent-container'>
  <div id='chart-title__1'>CHART 1 (working)</div>
  <div id='chart__1'></div>
  <div id='chart-title__2'>CHART 2 (not working)</div>
  <div id='chart__2'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake -- the 2nd data set is being returned by the API as strings instead of numbers, which is causing the chart to display incorrectly.

Love when it's a backend issue!